# I get the following error " TypeError: 'FoldersManager' object is not callable " when I try to upload a file into Box folder using JWT auth BOX SDK

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2, boxsdk

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxGWD.png)

Problem: I'm trying to upload files into BOX folder using JWT Authentication by making use of Box Sdk's (https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk-gen/blob/main/docs/authentication.md)

Error: I get the following error which says " FoldersManager" object is not callable when I use the following syntax.

```
new_file = client.folders(folder_id).upload('')
```

Code:

```
import json
import requests
from box_sdk_gen.client import BoxClient
from box_sdk_gen.jwt_auth import JWTConfig , BoxJWTAuth

jwt_config = JWTConfig.from_config_file('/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx /config.json')

auth = BoxJWTAuth(config=jwt_config)
user_auth = auth.as_user('3831914027')
client = BoxClient(user_auth)
folder_id = '223389277713'


new_file = client.folders(folder_id).upload('/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx /xxxx/part-00000-c69946d5-6a92-499f-8fec-01d06e48e6ca-c000.csv')
```

'''

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code there.  It's too hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I've attached the full code in the error screenshot

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Please post as plain text.

Comment: You're using `box_sdk_gen`, not `boxsdk`.  That documentation example is for `boxsdk`.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Added the code as plain text. Inorder to upload file using box_sdk_gen, what command do we need to use?